# ListView position is always retained when changing orientation in a Fragment

Tags: android

Now, I'm sure this will sound weird to many, but I have a problem with my ListView always retaining its position when rotating my device. It's not that this is a particularly bad behavior (it's what my goal is eventually, to have it remember the ListView position when a user rotates their device), it's more so that there doesn't seem to be a reason *why* it's retaining the position. I never told it to do that! Even when I try to force a change of my custom adapter on the ListView, it updates the information inside (the list items) but still retains the position of the element.

After further tests, if I try to make a delayed Runnable (about 300ms delay), I can successfully change the ArrayAdapter and the position resets to the top as expected.

Why is it forcing the ListView to change position during the creation of the Fragment (during onCreateView, onActivityCreated, etc)?

Here's some code:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
ListView list;
ArrayList<String> skinslist;
ArrayList<File> files;
ArrayList<Integer> heights;
File directory;
String[] listitems;
LinearLayout skin_list_error;
SkinListAdapter adapter;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
View view;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    listitems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TestStrings);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.skin_list);
    skin_list_error = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.skin_list_error);

    //Initialize list items
    if (isExternalStorageWritable() && isExternalStorageReadable()) {
        directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        //File directory = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "Mine");
        directory.mkdir();
        CreateNoMediaFile.CreateNoMedia(directory);
        File[] filedirectory = directory.listFiles();

        Arrays.sort(filedirectory, new Comparator<File>(){
            public int compare(File f1, File f2)
            {
                return Long.valueOf(f2.lastModified()).compareTo(f1.lastModified());
            } });

        skinslist = new ArrayList<String>();
        files = new ArrayList<File>();
        heights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (File f : filedirectory) {
            String filename = f.getName();
            if (filename.endsWith(".png")) {
            skinslist.add(f.getName().substring(0, filename.length() - 4));
            files.add(f);
            }
        }
        listitems = skinslist.toArray(new String[skinslist.size()]);
            adapter = new SkinListAdapter(this.getActivity(), listitems, files, heights);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: Couldn't access phone storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        list.setVisibility(ListView.GONE);
        skin_list_error.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    }
    //Finish initializing list items

    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshSkins(false);
        }

    });
    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(R.color.refresh_initial_color, 
            R.color.refresh_initial_color, 
            R.color.refresh_initial_color, 
            R.color.refresh_initial_color);

}
```

Here's where the view is inflated:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skinlist, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `view`? I suppose that in `onCreateView()`, so can you post its code?

Comment: Sure! I just added it to the main post.

Comment: Why do you call `super.onCreate()` from `onCreateView()`?

Comment: Hmm... I assumed it was necessary. I removed it and tried again (just as a test). Same results, sadly.

Comment: @Phascinate I think the question was due to calling through to the wrong superclass (`super.onCreate()` vs `super.onCreateView()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FragmentManager` saves and loads fragment's view state in its [moveToState()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState%28android.app.Fragment%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29) method. (Search for `saveFragmentViewState(f)` and `f.restoreViewState()`).

`saveFragmentViewState()` eventually calls `View.onSaveInstanceState()` for all views in hierarchy, so it saves `ListView` scroll positions, `EditText` content and many more.

Update: [corresponding documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState) (it's about `Activity`, but `Fragment` lifecycle is directed by `Activity` lifecycle):

> However, even if you do nothing and do not implement onSaveInstanceState(), some of the activity state is restored by the Activity class's default implementation of onSaveInstanceState(). Specifically, the default implementation calls the corresponding onSaveInstanceState() method for every View in the layout, which allows each view to provide information about itself that should be saved. Almost every widget in the Android framework implements this method as appropriate, such that any visible changes to the UI are automatically saved and restored when your activity is recreated. For example, the EditText widget saves any text entered by the user and the CheckBox widget saves whether it's checked or not. The only work required by you is to provide a unique ID (with the android:id attribute) for each widget you want to save its state. If a widget does not have an ID, then the system cannot save its state.

Comment: Thank you very much! I surprisingly never learned that, never mind that Activities worked that way as well.